# controller logic for gsp templates

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp

I'm working on organizing my gsp's into templates. The problem is that some of them require a fair amount of controller type logic (fetching data based on the current request, massaging it before display, etc). Currently it seems like I have two options:

1. Do the controller type work in the template itself using taglibs and scriptlet. This seems to be a poor separation of View and Controller. Plus it gets quite ugly quite quickly.
2. Do the controller type work in every controller that ultimately uses that template. This is not very DRY.

Neither of these seem quite MVC to me. What I'm looking for is a way to call a gsp template that has it's own controller. Is there such a thing in grails?

thanks,

Comment: Why not use <g:include> and include the template from the controller that has the template? This way the controller has all the logic about building the model in it and can be used from anywhere.

Comment: Very nice. Seems to be just what I was looking for. I implemented as follows:
in controller UserController I have a method:
_list() {...}

In User views I have a _list.gsp

and I call from the main gsp page like this:
<g:include controller="loan" action="_list"/>

Comment: It feels a little odd to have a method name that starts with the underscore character, but it certainly is exactly the functionality I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the method name to begin with an underscore?

Comment: The more usual thing is to have a method with a name like `list` and have it render `_list.gsp` with something like `render template: 'list'`.  When you render a template like that, the file name needs to begin with an underscore, like `_list.gsp`, but the method name would not.

Comment: using the render template:'list' is much nicer. thanks. A lot of ways to implement this it seems and I had been missing all of them... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to reuse your template (as you have defined here) is to actually include the call to the owning controller from your other GSP. Such as:

```
<g:include controller="myFancyControllerName" action="actionThatRendersTemplate" />
```

In doing so you are ensuring that the logic that builds the model used by the template is kept within the controller you are calling and you don't have to repeat it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a fair amount of logic into taglibs, or call services from a gsp. You don't have to put all your logic in a controller or call a controller from a GSP.